# Can my 84-year-old mother travel from Pune to Hydrabad with no ID documents?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, paperwork, domestic-travel

I am travelling from Pune to Hydrabad by Indigo with my mother. She is 84 years old. I have my passport but my mother doesn’t have any ID. Can we travel?